ERC721Enumerable - Getting all tokens owned by an address using balanceOf(owner) and tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, index)
I've been looking for a solution to retrieve all tokens from an address using ERC721Enumerable Openzeppelin extension. Please note that my purpose is not to get ALL tokens owned by an address, but all token owned by an address inside a smart contract. So I've been through several topics to find answers. As far as i understand, the different solutions can be sorted in two categories : on-chain and off-chain.
Being interested in on-chain solutions, i found this interesting topic: How to get all NFTs from an Enumerable ERC721 Smart Contract?.
It proposes a server-side approach using balanceOf(owner) and iterating index from 0 to balanceOf(owner) - 1 calling tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, index). This could be a great solution since it only use view functions but could cause UX issues for long token lists.
In this previous topic, a comment linked another topic with a smart contract solution here :
Issues looping arrays inside view functions, in Solidity
This time, a custom view function implementation is proposed, still using balanceOf(owner) and tokenOfOwnerByIndex(owner, index), but inside the smart contract. The function, with contributor's correction added, is as follows :
function tokensOfOwner(address _owner) public view returns(uint256[] memory){
    uint256 size =  balanceOf(_owner);
    uint256[] memory itemList = new uint256[](size); 
    for(uint256 i = 0; i < size; i++){
        itemList[i] = tokenOfOwnerByIndex(_owner, i);
    }
    return itemList;
}

The only concern is that this function returns an array, which could be problematic for long arrays or for gas management. However, the author specifies :

as far as I'm concerned the problem with arrays and out of gas issues are only when transactions are involved.

This solution seems to be the closest to what I'm looking for, but it's from 2021, and i didn't find any update about this subject. So my question is :
Is this on-chain solution considered as the final/better way to retrieve a list of tokens from an address using ERC721Eunumerable ?
If yes, can returning an array in a view function be concerning for gas optimisation and data consistency ?

That's the only solution to get all the tokens in a single call without using an external indexer.
You may have gas problem if the array ends up too big, but it should be safe for hundreds or thousands of elements. The actual upper limit depends on the gas limit of the RPC node you're using. That's generally around the block gas limit (30M), and assuming that every loop uses ~3000 gas, we get a limit of around ~10000 elements.

Hi, thank you very much for your edit and for your answer.  Problem solved
